# Readprocessmemory in C++ won't read

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, reverse-engineering, readprocessmemory

I have been coding for a few years now, but in 2016 I took a couple years off. Now I decided to come back, so I wanted to play around with some reverse engineering.
I played around with a game called Black Ops 1: Zombies. I found the memory addresses, then I went into C++ to code a simple cheat for unlimited ammo (This is offline), but it didn't work, so tried using ReadProcessMemory instead to see if it gives the correct ammo. The console started printing out "0". I thought there might been something with the code so I looked up some of my older source code, and the code was the same, tried installing VS 2015 instead in case the compiler is the problem, still nothing, tried GNCC compiler, still nothing. Tried using it on my second computer and it worked. I tried disabling Anti-Virus and windows defender but still nothing.
Here is the source code if it means anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD Address = 0x180A6C8;
DWORD pID;

int points;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {


        HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("Call of Duty®: BlackOps"));
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pID);
        HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pID);
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)Address, &points, sizeof(points), 0);
        cout << points << endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not doing any error handling. Does `FindWindow()` find a valid `HWND`? If so, does `OpenProcess()` return a valid `HANDLE`?  If so, does `ReadProcessMemory()` return TRUE? If any of them fail, what does `GetLastError()` say is the reason? Are you sure you even have the correct memory address? Make sure you are not being affected by [Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_howard/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista/). You should use an offset that is relative to the base address of the process you are reading from.

Comment: Tested all of it now, and still nothing, it works on my second computer so there is nothing wrong with the address or code, and Im not affected by ASLR

Comment: You are clearly doing something wrong. What I described will work fine on all computers if you use it correctly, perform adequate error handling, and have proper permissions to access the target process.

Comment: GetLastError returns 0, got a string function for it, also null, I tried disabling security, anti-virus, firewall, windows defender etc, and starting in admin mode, still returns 0. I tried using another game that uses modules, but this returned something like -66756576
I don't know what more permission is needed than admin + disabling possible factors blocking

Comment: I also tried disabling UAC, and still nothing

Comment: I did no changes to code or computer, and today it was magically working again. funny but strange :/

Answer (score 0):

A.) Can you read the Address in Cheat Engine etc

B.) Does it require a base address (e.g "client.dll")?  If so get the module base address of the required module.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that ? There are tags and the question is pretty straight forward: Why it won't read from memory on one computer when it does on the other one